# Selenium WebDriver Suddenly Slows to a Crawl

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I'm running a bunch of Selenium tests one after the next which initially runs at normal speed. However, at one point my console displays the following errors:

```
JavaScript warning: https://www.somedomain.com/xx/xx line 10991 > injectedScript, line 1: WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER.

###!!! [Parent][PGPUParent] Error: RunMessage(msgname=PGPU::Msg_ShutdownVR) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

---

```
JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(serverJavaScript error: resourc)s/de://activity-stream/lib/PuersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.
mmy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.
JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.
JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/duJavaScmmy/blript erocklist//ror is : rnot ea vasliod URL.
urce://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.
JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.
```

---

```
console.error: "Failed to fetch undefinedmain-workspace/personality-provider-models/170a56ca-c1bf-4181-9b30-693002f7e245.json: "
console.error: "Failed to fetch undefinedmain-workspace/personality-provider-models/06e44aaa-324b-47ac-b458-72e1bccdf86b.json: "
```

There are hundreds of such messages being displayed in the console and Selenium is barley scraping any data anymore. **It is essentially crippling Selenium**.

What is causing the above errors to (suddenly) appear and why is it slowing down Selenium?

What can I do to fix/prevent this?

I'm using `Selenium` version 3.141.59 with `Firefox WebDriver` (*Gecko driver*) & `Java`.

Thanks

Comment: Try switching to chrome

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for your suggestion but my current code is optimized to work with Firefox so switching to Chrome just to solve one issue seems like an overkill at this point..

Comment: Ok. I hope you can figure it out by yourself in that case, because you're probably on your own.

Comment: @pguardiario How would you suggest I go about trying to debug this? Is there any info I can add you think will be helpful? **A small update**: I let the program run overnight and nothing has changed.. essentially Selenium is not working anymore and is just printing a bunch of errors to console as seen in OP.. `JavaScript error: resource://activity-stream/lib/PersonalityProvider/PersonalityProvider.jsm, line 68: TypeError: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist// is not a valid URL.`

Comment: It's a javascript issue, it's caused by the website not selenium